# angular js ng-view returns blanc partials -- Express/ Jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am writing an angular application following a tutorial. To my surprise, i followed exactly and my node js is starting fine without an issue. However, my angular is not returning the template as suppose to . I saw a similar problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365044/ng-view-not-working-with-partials-in-angularjs-express)  same tutorial and the same issue. However, the question was not answered .  Below is my dir structure

[image]

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
});


angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
});
```

My layout.jade

```
doctype html
head
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
body(ng-app='app')
   block main-content
   include scripts
```

My main.jade

```
h1 This is a partial
h2 {{ myVar }}
```

The route in my server.js are set as

```
app.get('partials/:partialPath',function(req,res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});
app.get('*', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

my index.jade

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
    section.content
       div(ng-view)
```

Althought i am thinking that shouldn't be an issue because i am starting with a partial view which is part of a page. When i run,  my page return black. I inspect the element and ensured that all the js and css where loaded. When i view the source,  a html source below was generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><link rel="styleSheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="styleSheet" href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css">
<link rel="styleSheet" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <section class="content">
   <div ng-view></div></section>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I was suspecting routeProvider from my app.js here

```
.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
```

tried

```
.when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
```

All to no avail . please where do i go wrong ?  I have tried everything possible. I even restarted the tut yet still blanc. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you add .html to your path?

Comment: @MatthewBrown my path is in .jade . I tried .jade and .html , both failed. I am confused .

Comment: Are you using a build system like grunt?

Comment: @MatthewBrown never heard of it.  I am running node server, angular and jade engine , stylus, etc. There is no grunt .

Comment: Hmm well something must be compiling jade to html, As far as I know angular can't handle jade files directly, I'm thinking you must have something converting it

Comment: @MatthewBrown i thought jade engine does that . You can from the gen html above as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time. It turns out the issue is in my layout

```
doctype html
head
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
body(ng-app='app')
   block main-content
   include scripts
```

Changed to

```
 doctype html
    head
       base(href='/')
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
    body(ng-app='app')
       block main-content
       include scripts
```

What was missing is

```
base(href='/')
```

It does not load the templates if you remove that base. I learnt that from another tut video by tut plus "[Tuts Plus] Building a Web App From Scratch With AngularJS Video Tutorial" . The presenter specifically mentioned the important of the `base(href='/')` and warned never to forget . Alternatively , there is another good example from @Alex Choroshin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099992/can-angular-be-used-within-a-jade-template/21100175#21100175) . you should download the doc he suggested . Its a perfect example. Thanks