# angular partial not rendering with jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am building an angular app following a tut. However, my angular `ng-view` is not rendering. I have seen a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365044/ng-view-not-working-with-partials-in-angularjs-express)  yet it has not been answered.  Below is my dir structure

[image]

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
});


angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
});
```

My layout.jade

```
doctype html
head
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
body(ng-app='app')
   block main-content
   include scripts
```

My main.jade

```
h1 This is a partial
h2 {{ myVar }}
```

The route in my server.js are set as

```
app.get('partials/:partialPath',function(req,res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});
app.get('*', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

my index.jade

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
    section.content
       div(ng-view)
```

Although I am thinking that shouldn't be an issue because I am starting with a partial view which is part of a page. When I run my page it returns black. I inspected the elements and ensured that all the `js` and `css` where loaded. The html source below was generated on my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><link rel="styleSheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="styleSheet" href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css">
<link rel="styleSheet" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <section class="content">
   <div ng-view></div></section>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I was suspecting `routeProvider` from my app.js here

```
.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
```

tried

```
.when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
```

All to no avail. Please where do I go wrong ?  I have tried everything possible. I even restarted the tut yet still blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `'partials/main.html'` ? That's what I have in one of my `$stateProvider`s. I checked, and the extension is there. May work without it, mind.

Comment: yes sir i did, also my partial is in .jade . i tried .html nd .jade , both failed.

Comment: Can't be .jade anyway, it needs to be html. Any errors in the console?

Comment: there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time. It turns out the issue is in my layout

```
doctype html
head
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
   link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
body(ng-app='app')
   block main-content
   include scripts
```

Changed to

```
 doctype html
    head
       base(href='/')
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/bootstrap.css")
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
       link(rel="styleSheet",href="css/site.css")
    body(ng-app='app')
       block main-content
       include scripts
```

What was missing is

```
base(href='/')
```

It does not load the templates if you remove that base. I learnt that from another tut video by tut plus "[Tuts Plus] Building a Web App From Scratch With AngularJS Video Tutorial" . The presenter specifically mentioned the important of the `base(href='/')` and warned never to forget . Alternatively , there is another good example from @Alex Choroshin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099992/can-angular-be-used-within-a-jade-template/21100175#21100175) . you should download the doc he suggested . Its a perfect example. Thanks